# span tag background color not working in swing application

Tags: java, html, swing

I am displaying text in jlist using html.  The background color is not changing for the span tag.  Is there any way I can try to change background color?  I also want to know if there is any tool/online site where we can validate html for Swing applications.

```
<span 'background-color=green'> <b>Name : </b> </span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background-color` is a CSS style, you can add it to an HTML element with `style` attribute:

```
<span style="background-color:green"> <b>Name : </b> </span>
```

You can validate HTML using W3C Markup Validation Service: http://validator.w3.org/